# Base58 Encoder function in PostgreSQL for TEXT

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, base58

Can anyone help me to implement Base58 encoding stored procedure in PostgreSQL.

I've found answer for [numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757377/base58-encoder-function-in-postgresql/34759277#34759277) but I'm looking for similar stored procedure that can accept TEXT or VARCHAR value.

Answer (score 1):

On this very rare occasion I'm going to suggest you don't do this.  It will be computationally possible but highly inadvisable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base58

> In contrast to Base64, the digits of the encoding don't line up well
>   with byte boundaries of the original data. For this reason, the method
>   is well-suited to encode large integers, but not designed to encode
>   longer portions of binary data.

To put this another way, Base58 is not designed to encode strings / text.  Your main alternatives are:

- Base64 which if copied manually by a human, the human may make mistakes.  Otherwise Base64 is safe to copy / paste
- Hexadecimal which is easily copied by humans but significantly longer than Base64

If you feel you really *need* Base58 and not Base64 then it may be worth editing your requirements into your question.  This may help someone give an answer more specific to your requiremnts:

- What are these strings you need to convert (examples are preferable)?
- Why do they need to be Base58 and not Base64 (what other system are you passing these to)?